# optimizing a max function subquery

Tags: oracle, optimization, plsql, max

I need some help with a optimizing query.

```
SELECT DISTINCT se.id, se.date_time_stamp, se.event_date_time, se.event_type_id, se.resource_id
  FROM   view1 se, view2 rs
 WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM view3 ds
                 WHERE ds.dataset_id = dataset_id_
                   AND rs.contract   = ds.contract
                   AND rs.active    ='TRUE')
                   AND se.resource_id = rs.resource_id
                   AND se.event_type_id  IN ('BO','BF')      
                   AND se.event_date_time >= ( SELECT  MAX(rs.start_datetime)-NVL(NVL(functioApi.Get_Snap_Time(rs.company_id,rs.emp_no),functioApi1.Get_Snap_Time(rs.company_id,rs.resource_type)),0)
                                                 FROM  view4 sse
                                                WHERE  se.resource_id = sse.resource_id
                                                  AND  SYSDATE <= sse.end_datetime);
```

Above query will take to execute approximately 5 hours. Bottleneck is with the part MAX(rs.start_datetime)in subquery. I have tried several options yet the required data is not selected or no performance improvement.
In here the view2 which takes data from global temp table table ombined with another view
Strang thing is I create a index for this global temp table Then the above statement will not fetch data during run time.

Appreciate any suggestions to improve this.

Comment: How could anyone here help you without any idea of db version, execution plan, what the functions you're calling do, .... Help us to help you. If creating an index makes the query return no rows, while it does return something without the index is surely a bug.

Comment: db veriosn is 12c Release 12.1.0.1.0. As i mentioned issue is in MAX function not in fucntion APis. You can ignore that part if needed.

Comment: Where are your indexes?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the purpose and some sample data it would be difficult to help you.

One starting point could be this one:

```
WITH t AS (
    SELECT sse.resource_id, MAX(rs.start_datetime) AS MAX_start_datetime
    FROM view4 sse
    WHERE SYSDATE <= sse.end_datetime
    GROUP BY resource_id)
SELECT DISTINCT se.id, se.date_time_stamp, se.event_date_time, se.event_type_id, se.resource_id
FROM view1 se
   JOIN view2 rs ON se.resource_id = rs.resource_id
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
               FROM view3 ds
               WHERE ds.dataset_id = dataset_id_
                   AND rs.contract = ds.contract
                   AND rs.active ='TRUE')
    AND se.event_type_id  IN ('BO','BF')      
    AND se.event_date_time >= (
        SELECT MAX_start_datetime - NVL(NVL(functioApi.Get_Snap_Time(rs.company_id,rs.emp_no),functioApi1.Get_Snap_Time(rs.company_id,rs.resource_type)),0))
        FROM t
        WHERE se.resource_id = t.resource_id)
```